# Old sci-fi story about the guy waking up women from cryostasis

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, cryogenics

It involved a long-term space trip and the inhabitants could only be put to sleep once because the second cryo was too much for their body and they would die. The man literally went through every woman on board, saying that they both had woken up by accident and they had to spend their lives together, then killing them with the cryo gun. He was just biding his time till he got his fill and could wake up his true love, but the twist ending was she was intending to do the same thing as he was but with the men, and kills him with the cryo gun.

I found this story in a old sci-fi magazine in my art college's library, and want to know it's name so I can call a "I told you so!" with how Passengers has turned out to be.

Comment: Welcome feel free to take a [tour] of the site, and see [ask] for details about asking a great question.

Comment: I think I just read this story in last six months or so, but now I can't remember what anthology it was in.

Comment: Yes, please remove that totally gratuitous spoiler.

Comment: I believe that Joe L. is correct, that is was a text story and not a comic.  When I first heard about "Passengers", I'd wondered if it was based on an old story.  I can't remember where I read it either.

Answer (score 5):

Before reading this answer be aware that it contains a link to an article that reveals major spoilers about the movie "Passengers".

You are right on about the plot being taken from an old EC comic - *Weird Science* #20 July/August 1953 - "50 Girls 50" - story by Al Feldstein and art by Al Williamson. The story has appeared in various collections, most notably "[50 Girls 50 and Other Stories (The EC Comics Library)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1606995774)". There's an article on a website called Jalopnik.com entitled "[The Plot of Passengers Seems to be Based on this Old '50s Comic Strip](http://jalopnik.com/the-plot-of-passengers-seems-to-be-based-on-this-old-50-1790446713)" that addresses this very topic.